# How can I set a time limit for automatically resuming on the Bluemix Conversation service

Tags: ibm-cloud, chatbot, watson-conversation

I made a conversation bot with Bluemix Watson Conversation and connected it with a chat app. But I have a problem.

My bot asked something and was waiting for response from user - user finished the conversation but didn’t get out of the app. And user came back after a few hours and tried to start new conversation with my bot. (ex. Greeting hi bot!) But the conversation was continued from the point where previous conversation was stopped.

I want to prevent that problem by setting a time limit. If user doesn’t response within the time limit, the original conversation will end. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, 
I had the same question a few weeks ago. And I search about that. 
Inside dwAnswers I did what I need to do that.

You need to write this into your application code. 
The *Conversation Service* just returns a `json` and it's up to your app to know what to do with it.

Or, you could create a `context variable` for delay the timeout, and that cues your app to delay. But it will require custom code too!

Reference: [dwAnswers](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwietaLNqqzTAhUDEZAKHd42AJAQFgg0MAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.ibm.com%2Fanswers%2Fquestions%2F321014%2Fwatson-conversation-dialog-timeout-or-wait-period.html&usg=AFQjCNGyeHesCdVwCPjzyqWTBB5ZXVjMiQ&sig2=puGeo5FPNgoU2cjDcz1CBw) - IBM Developer Official.

Comment: Thanks! There's a lot of help

Answer (score 0):

The normal behavior here is to place a timing loop into your client code. The loop waits for a period of time, and then reprompts the user do they still wish to ask a question. If not they close down the conversation. Which means that the conversation context is reset to empty. Thus when the user next returns at a later stage they will not pass in the previous context payload, but a blank context element ( or no context element). Which will result in the Watson conversation service issuing a new conversation id, and starting from the beginning again.

Comment: Thanks! There's a lot of help